# Subquery in SELECT statement with aggregated output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, correlated-subquery

I am trying to use subquery and the group by in Select statement but the query is taking long time to execute with the actual data set which will be in few 100 thousands.

Example data set below

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
Fkey INT,
BGkey INT,
Amt DECIMAL(10,4))          


CREATE TABLE #Temp2
(
Fkey INT,
CFkey INT,
Amt DECIMAL(10,4),
JobID INT,
PostedDate DATE)

INSERT INTO #Temp1
(Fkey,
BGkey,
Amt)

SELECT 1001,1,20.32
UNION ALL
SELECT 1002,2,10.32
UNION ALL
SELECT 1002,3,40.32

INSERT INTO #Temp2
(Fkey,
CFkey,
Amt,
JobID, PostedDate)

SELECT 1001,11,20.32,504, '2014-10-20'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1001,11,-20.32, NULL, '2014-10-27'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1001,13,20.32, 510, '2014-10-27'
```

Expected output results

```
CFKEY   BGKey   BGAMT   CFAmt
11  1   NULL    0
13  1   20.32   20.32
```

Query 1 output  --> this is incorrect

Query1;

```
 Select CF.CFkey, BG.BGkey, SUM(BG.Amt) AS BGAmt, SUM(Cf.Amt) AS CFAmt  from #Temp2 CF
 INNER JOIN #Temp1 BG
 ON BG.Fkey = CF.Fkey
 WHERE CF.Fkey=1001
 group by CF.CFkey, BG.BGkey
```

Query 1 outut - which is incorrect the BGAmt is doubled up

```
CFkey   BGkey   BGAmt   CFAmt
11  1   40.64   0
13  1   20.32   20.32
```

Query 2: Getting expected result but it is taking time with actual data set

```
 SELECT OUT.CFKEY,
 OUT.BGKey ,
 SUM(OUT.BGAMT) AS BGAMT,
 SUM(OUT.CFAmt) AS CFAmt FROM (
  Select CF.CFkey, BG.BGkey, 
  (SELECT T1.Amt from #Temp1 T1
    WHERE T1.Fkey = CF.Fkey
    AND CF.JobID IS NOT NULL
    AND CF.PostedDate IN ( SELECT MAX(T3.PostedDate) FROM #Temp2 T3
    WHERE T3.Fkey = CF.Fkey)) AS BGAMT,
Cf.Amt AS CFAmt from #Temp2 CF
 INNER JOIN #Temp1 BG
 ON BG.Fkey = CF.Fkey
 WHERE CF.Fkey=1001) AS OUT
 group by OUT.CFKEY,
 OUT.BGKey
```

Query 2 - result set [ correct result] but query needs to be optimized

```
CFKEY   BGKey   BGAMT   CFAmt
11  1   NULL    0
13  1   20.32   20.32
```

Can any of you please help to optimise this query. Is there any other way to get this correct result?

Comment: Are you actually running this query against temp tables that have no indices or primary keys, or is that just for the sake of the question?

Comment: you do know you can use values (), (), () syntax?

Comment: I am running the same logic on different data sets which are in some thousands but the query takes more than an hour to execute. So need to know is there any i can optimze the logic but gets the same expected result?

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but this is a view of what it looks like
that is just messed up - two levels of #temp1 and #temp2
what are you trying to do?

```
SELECT OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey 
     , SUM(OUT.BGAMT) AS BGAMT
     , SUM(OUT.CFAmt) AS CFAmt 
  FROM (  Select CF.CFkey, BG.BGkey
                ,( SELECT T1.Amt 
                     from #Temp1 T1
                    WHERE T1.Fkey = CF.Fkey
                      AND CF.JobID IS NOT NULL
                      AND CF.PostedDate IN ( SELECT MAX(T3.PostedDate) 
                                               FROM #Temp2 T3
                                              WHERE T3.Fkey = CF.Fkey
                                           )
                 ) AS BGAMT
                ,Cf.Amt AS CFAmt 
            from #Temp2 CF
            JOIN #Temp1 BG
              ON BG.Fkey = CF.Fkey
           WHERE CF.Fkey=1001
       ) AS OUT
 group by OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey
```

Your naming made following the source difficult:

```
SELECT OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey 
     , SUM(OUT.BGAMT) AS BGAMT
     , SUM(OUT.CFAmt) AS CFAmt 
  FROM (  Select Temp2a.CFkey, Temp1a.BGkey
                ,( SELECT Temp1b.Amt 
                     from #Temp1 Temp1b
                    WHERE Temp1b.Fkey = Temp2a.Fkey
                      AND Temp2a.JobID IS NOT NULL
                      AND Temp2a.PostedDate IN ( SELECT MAX(Temp2b.PostedDate) 
                                                   FROM #Temp2 Temp2b
                                                  WHERE Temp2b.Fkey = Temp2a.Fkey
                                               )
                 ) AS BGAMT
                ,Cf.Amt AS CFAmt 
            from #Temp2 Temp2a --CF
            JOIN #Temp1 Temp1a --BG
              ON Temp1a.Fkey = Temp2a.Fkey
           WHERE Temp2a.Fkey = 1001
       ) AS OUT
 group by OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey
```

Optimize 1:

```
SELECT OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey 
     , SUM(OUT.BGAMT) AS BGAMT
     , SUM(OUT.CFAmt) AS CFAmt 
  FROM (  Select Temp2a.CFkey, Temp1a.BGkey
                ,( SELECT Temp1b.Amt 
                     from #Temp1 Temp1b
                    WHERE Temp1b.Fkey = Temp2a.Fkey
                      AND Temp2a.JobID IS NOT NULL
                      AND Temp2a.PostedDate IN ( SELECT MAX(Temp2b.PostedDate) 
                                                   FROM #Temp2 Temp2b
                                                  WHERE Temp2b.Fkey = 1001
                                               )
                 ) AS BGAMT
                ,Cf.Amt AS CFAmt 
            from #Temp2 Temp2a --CF
            JOIN #Temp1 Temp1a --BG
              ON Temp1a.Fkey = Temp2a.Fkey
             AND Temp2a.Fkey = 1001
       ) AS OUT
 group by OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey
```

optimize 2 - it may not be correct but it should give you some ideas

```
SELECT OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey 
     , SUM(OUT.BGAMT) AS BGAMT
     , SUM(OUT.CFAmt) AS CFAmt 
  FROM (  Select Temp2a.CFkey, Temp1a.BGkey, Temp1b.Amt, Temp2a.Amt AS CFAmt
               , Row_Number() (order by  Temp2a.PostedDate desc) as row                     
            from #Temp2 Temp2a --CF
            JOIN #Temp1 Temp1a --BG
              ON Temp1a.Fkey = Temp2a.Fkey
             AND Temp2a.Fkey = 1001
             AND Temp2a.JobID IS NOT NULL
       ) AS OUT
 where out.row = 1
 group by OUT.CFKEY, OUT.BGKey
```